# Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i have a hudge problem while integrating a new library on Android App.

When i tried to `implementation 'br.com.stone:stone-sdk:3.8.2'` on Gradle (app module) and sync project, android shows a new issue

```
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar (xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c)
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar (xpp3:xpp3_min:1.1.4c)
```

Perhaps implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar') has already the same Class.

Can anynone help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer for reference, based on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59341. All you need to do is to add 3 items in app/build.gradle:

1. ```
   shrinkResources false
   minifyEnabled false
   ```
2. ```
   configurations {
       all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
   }
   ```
3. ```
   implementation 'xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.4d_b4_min'
   ```

PS: I used this solution fix a similar issue (just replaced "xpp3" with "xmlpull" in item #2):

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser found in modules jetified-kxml2-2.3.0 (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and jetified-xmlpull-1.1.3.4d_b4_min (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.4d_b4_min)
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException found in modules jetified-kxml2-2.3.0 (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and jetified-xmlpull-1.1.3.4d_b4_min (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.4d_b4_min)
```